# How can zoom image with multiple Touch in android?

Tags: android

I am going to create image gallery. How can i zoom image using multiple touch. i got pinch-0.8 library but how can i use it. if you have any other idea then help me.

Zoom effect with ImageView in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library available at **[Image Zoom](http://code.google.com/p/danbooru-gallery-android/source/browse/src/it/sephiroth/android/library/imagezoom/?r=b2ae3248f1182073290a19e76f32f76c4eb4a181)**

Download two files

- ImageViewTouch.java
- ImageViewTouchBase.java

To use image view inside your layout file, write following code

```
<com.package_name.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

**NoTe**

Make sure, you have put those files inside any **package**, like **com.customview** or something like that. So that you can refer that in layout file.

Link

You can download sample from  [sephiroth/ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)